# how to take backup of specific tables of a schema and restore on other schema

Tags: postgresql, backup

Suppose i have two databases in postgres

```
DB1
    schema_abc
    schema_xyz
    ...........
DB2
    schema_lol
    schema_qwx
```

Now i want to take backup of specific tables of schema_abc and restore them on schema_lol.

I am using **pg_dump -U postgres DB1 --schema=schema_abc -t tbl1 -t tbl4 > file_name.sql**

but search_path will be schema_abc in sql file, how can i restore this sql file to differently named schema of different db i.e schema_lol of DB2

Comment: Is it mandatory to use pg_dump? Maybe you can do what you want through a Foreign Data Wrapper? (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)

Comment: Could you just restore to schema_abc in DB2 and then rename the schema?